# Avoid writing HTML by coding in Java

Tags: java, html, swing

I want to avoid writing `<table></table>` and other stuff like that, by writing Java (or Python) classes. Example:

```
Html html = new Html(); obj.setCoordinates(120,50); html.add(obj);
```

Which API is the best for this ?

**Update**

I'm currently trying Vaadin, a Java web framework which extends GWT. It offers web functionality with a coding style similar to a desktop API.

Comment: Why? That approach results in code that's much harder to change and maintain later.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Depends on the level of abstraction. If you've also got things like progressbar or slider built-in, it results in less code.

Comment: @Jim It's a trade-off, one of the biggest .com's use this approach (it's an in-house app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question.  Like others say, it's an extremely bad idea to move all of the HTML generation into your code in terms of printing out HTML elements.  A better approach is to create a template for the HTML you're trying to create, leaving holes into which you insert your dynamic content (e.g. you have a place where the rows of your tables will be inserted. I use [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) and it sounds good for what you're trying to do.  See the Fill A Table example in this [introductory page](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/stringtemplate.html)

Answer (score 4):

You might try something like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).  It's a widget library where you code in Java and it is compiled into Javascript, with the DOM/HTML being created when you load the page.

I'm not sure I'd recommend it for content that is relatively static from an interaction standpoint (not using Javascript after loading, not using AJAX, etc).  It's primarily meant to be a Web app platform, not a way to use Java as your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

There was [Jakarta ECS](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/), but its retired now. Alternatively you can use a Java based template engine: [Apache velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/)

Comment: you'd still be writing html when using a templating engine.

Comment: yes, but that was the closed to the OPs requirements. Otherwise, ECS is the best solution.

Comment: +1, I wrote my own version of ECS a decade ago to learn recursion in Java. It was a neat little project. HTML code is very easy to generate using this approach

Answer (score 1):

Ditto to Mr Garrison's comment.

I presently work on a system that's filled with functions that write HTML. So instead of writing, say,

```
out.println("<input name=x size=10 value='foo'>")
```

by the clever use of a set of HTML tag objects, they simply write:

```
InputTag x=new InputTag();
x.setName("x");
x.setSize(10);
x.setValue("foo");
out.println(x.toHtml());
```

Yeah, that saves so much work!

Comment: this does not answer the question but gives a personal opinion. I really should down vote it. But since you're giving a personal opinion I'll give mine. Sure hard coded values are easy to output in a string. The benefit of the second approach is when the values are contained in variables. Try writing HTML where you have to start escaping all the strings and manange end tags like when using multiple rows in a table.

Comment: @camickr: When a friend says, "I've decided to shoot myself. How do I load this revolver?", a direct answer to the question is not necessarily the most useful response. That said, writing a function to properly escape a string for use in HTML is a good idea because it shortens your code over re-writing that logic every time you need it. I use such a function in almost every web app I write. Writing a function to output "<p>" for you is not a good idea, because the function call is not going to be any shorter than out.println("<p>") and just serves to hide what you're doing.

Comment: What about tags that require an end tag? They can easily be forgotton using your approach. An HTML generator like the OP wants also removes this worry so you know you have proper formatted and generated code every time. Manually coding HTML string is error prone. Yes, there is an overhead for this type of safety and ease of HTML generation, but that is what the posteer asked for. Writing code is not about how few characters you can use to write the code. Its about ease or reading, ease of maintaining etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote some classes & code for doing the type of thing you're thinking of, in Python. I'd really recommend using Python over Java for this.  And as to some of the comments, yes it WAS easier.  I didn't have to worry about escaping, quoting or matching the closing  so much, as the code was constructed to look for an objects members and format them as attributes in the html output.  Python's introspection is great for this.